# regarding formatting of timestamp

Tags: java

Can you please suggest how to display Timestamp value in format "dd MonthName" format for e.g. "Tue Jun 25 21:56:17 IST 2013" should be display as "25 June" . I'm using below code but it is not working .

```
Date dNow = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("d M");
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
```

Comment: Try the instructions [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: "it is not working" is *never* enough detail. You should show the result you're getting, vs the result you actually wanted - and ideally what research you've done into diagnosing it.

Comment: ok Jon Skeet , noted your point . Since I got answer hence not providing detail . will follow it from next time while posting question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the format as `"dd MMMMM"` as

> dd: Day in month (2 digit day number)
>
> MMMMM: Month in year

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMMMM");
```

Read more about SimpleDateFormat here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

You are using a wrong pattern. your pattern should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd MMM");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern for "25 June" should be:

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("d MMMM");
```